# How to deal with the infant who has got an eyelash in the eye?

Tags: infant

The kid is 5 months old.

She keeps on rubbing her eyes repeatedly throughout the day. Last time I did see an eyelash in one of her eyes.

What's the way out?

Answer (score 2):

We had one incident with a baby and an foreign object in his eyes. We solved it but sitting down with the kid in the bathtub and playing around. Whenever he would open is his eyes, I just splashed a two full hands of water in his face. He wasn't happy about this but some after distraction he would relax and play again. So we just repeated this until the object came out. The alternative would have been to go to an eyey doctor who would camp the eye open. We were trying to avoid that.

Comment: Instead of splashing, you could also try gently pouring water over baby's head while in the tub (just as you might when rinsing hair) or taking him for a little swim where his face is briefly swept through water. As Hilmar suggests, make a little game of it. Eyes are designed to clear themselves of most debris, and adding a little extra water can speed the process.

Comment: Good point. Obviously you start things easy and escalate slowly as necessary. Fortunately this one was a big water fan so even heavy splashing was tolerable. He went on to become the captain of the swim team and missed the state championship in the 100 yard butterfly by 1/100 of a second, so I think it's safe to assume that no large permanent psychological damage was done :-)